# Java delete folder still exists

Tags: java

I have a block of code:

```
List<String> unusedFolders = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < unusedFolders.size(); i++) {
    File dirDate = new File(unusedFolders.get(i));

    String[] files = dirDate.list();

    for(String f: files) {
        File file = new File(dirDate.getPath(),f);
        file.delete();
    }

    dirDate.delete();
    //dirDate.deleteOnExit();
    }
```

The list "unusedFolder" has values like:

```
C:\opt\transmission\tejas\transform\inv\20140927
C:\opt\transmission\tejas\transform\inv\20140928
C:\opt\transmission\tejas\transform\inv\20140929
```

It ran with no errors in eclipse but when I check in the windows explorer, the folders are still there and when I try to access it (click). It prompts:

```
C:\opt\transmission\tejas\transform\inv\20140927 is not accessible. Access is Denied.
```

Now, I can't even delete it manually. Anyone has an idea? thank you.

Comment: try googling to see how you can change read/write persmissions of a folder or file. Make your code set rw permissions and see if it helps.

Comment: There is no guarantee that `File#delete` will succeed and you should check the return result from the method

Comment: have you checked File/Folder permission, Security permission? add your user and then try it again, it may help you

Comment: I would change that code to use `listFiles(),` which simplifies everything, and to delete the contents recursively.

Comment: Is the owner of the file/folder same as the one that is being used to run the program? Check the ownership properties of the folder. If you cannot access these folders, you may need to boot in safe mode, take the ownership and then delete these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This most certainly the work of a WIndows environment. Some other process must be holding the lock to the folder or its contents. Once you have identified the process which is holding the lock and kill it, u will certainly be able to delete the folder.

If ur not sure of the process that is accesing the folder , u might consider restarting ur machine.

Comment: Just wanted to not that I searched forever for that locking method, because for me the directory only went away after exiting the JVM. The culprit was `Files.list(...).forEach(...)`. That was quite surprising and frustrating at the same time...

Answer (score 1):

Typically when something like this happens, it happens on Windows.

That's because Windows can enforce a type of filesystem lock where the file won't disappear until it is no longer used.  Check to see if you have an old copy of "something" running which might be keeping the file (in this case, the directory) open.  If so, killing the program will typically allow the delete to complete.

That's assuming it is not something rather simple, like directory write permissions on the parent directory (which must be rewritten for a child directory to be removed).